# How to zoom on a Laravel AreaChart?

Tags: laravel, charts

Is it possible to have an area Laravel chart on which we can zoom to have a closer look on it?
I have an area chart with three components to show, two of them having very close values i would like to zoom into onclick.

Comment: What library or package are you using for this?

Comment: I'm using the framework laravel 5.2 with lavacharts 3.0

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with laravel. You should check the chart plugin's documentation if it support the zoom mechanism that you want. If it's not, You should find other plugin.